React Native expo 404 error for app url after expo export to deployment environment
I have broken my react native app into two components - CancerHomepageApp and ChemoHomepageApp. When I run the app locally I can access each app by going to http://localhost:8081/cancer and http://localhost:8081/chemo.  However when I deploy my app to the google cloud, which uses firebase, I get a 404 error.

Here is my index.js file which has the App screens:
import { MainSideBarWeb } from './MainSideBarWeb.js';
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer linking={{
            prefixes: ['http://localhost:8081', 'http://cancer-hacked.web.app'],
            config: {
                screens: {
                    CancerHomepageWeb: 'cancer',
                    ChemoHomepageWeb: 'chemo'
                }
            }
        }}>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="CancerHomepageWeb">
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="CancerHomepageWeb"
                    component={CancerHomepageWeb}
                    options={{ title: 'Cancer Homepage' }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="ChemoHomepageWeb"
                    component={ChemoHomepageWeb}
                    options={{ title: 'Chemo Homepage' }}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
        );
};
export default registerRootComponent(App);

Here is my deployment script:
npx expo export -p web
mv dist/index.html src/main/www/index.html
mv dist/metadata.json src/main/www/
mv dist/favicon.ico src/main/www/
rm -rf src/main/www/assets
mv dist/assets src/main/www/assets
rm -rf src/main/www/_expo
mv dist/_expo src/main/www/_expo
firebase deploy


Shouldnt you make "http" this "https"

Thanks! I tried with https://cancer-hacked.web.app but am still not able to get the cancer or chemo page when adding that to the URL.

I can hit your app on https. This seems to be resolved. I believe you were trying to hit the http route. Can you confirm?


Thank you for your post. I get the cancer page but when I put in  a URL for cancer or chemo I still get a 404 error.  This happens for both  pages: https://cancer-hacked.web.app/cancer and https://cancer-hacked.web.app/chemo
